# iOS 6 turn by turn navigation API

Tags: ios, api, mapkit, navigator, ios6

Is there anyone who can give me same reference, support, example link or other info about iOS 6 Map API?
(I made a long search on the web finding only the apple reference)

First of all I'm interested in "turn by turn navigation" feature and its integration in custom app.

Thanks to all

Comment: Any post on iOS 6 specific issues are currently in violation of Apple's NDA. You can talk about this inside Apple's developer discussion boards, if you are a paying developer, otherwise you will have to wait until iOS 6 is released.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with [WWDC 2012 session 300](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=300), which includes references to other sources of information at the end.